# Similar matrices C and D: how to derive the relation $\mathbf{x} = S^{-1} \mathbf{y}$ when $C = S^{-1}DS$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

D (with corresponding eigenvector $\mathbf{x}$) and 
C (with corresponding $\mathbf{y}$)
are similar matrices, which means they have the same eigenvalues.

So the relation $C = S^{-1}DS$ holds.

So we get these relations:
$C\mathbf{x} = \lambda \mathbf{x} $
and 
$ D\mathbf{y} = \lambda \mathbf{y}$

How can we with these details arrive to the equality?:
$\mathbf{x} = S^{-1} \mathbf{y} $

Comment: I think there's a mistake in "So we get these relations..." . According to what you wrote, i t must be $\;Cy=\lambda y\;,\;\;Dx=\lambda x\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $C$ with $D$ you get $ D S x = \lambda S x$, so $S x$ is an eigenvector of $D$.

Comment: I see how the derivation was achieved as long as this was relevant/given: $S^{-1}DS=C$

Now, however given the new relation: $S^{-1}DS=kC$, how do you come to the exact same conclusion (it is supposed to be the case)?

Comment: You have $D S x = k \lambda S x$ in this case, so same conclusion as long as $k\ne 0$.

Answer (score 2):

An idea:

$$C=S^{-1}DS\iff CS^{-1}=S^{-1}D\implies \color{red}{CS^{-1}x}=S^{-1}Dx=S^{-1}(\lambda x)=\color{red}{\lambda S^{-1}x}$$

Thus, $\;S^{-1}x\;$ is an eigenvalue of $\;C\;$ corresponding to $\;\lambda\;$ . Now, if the corresponding eigenspaces (for $\;C, D\;$) are one-dimensional, then we already get $\;ky=S^{-1}x\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb F\;$, so I'm not sure the claim is true as written.

Comment: Even for one-dimensional eigenspaces you can multiply $y$ by units no?

Comment: @simonzack I don't understand: *what* units?

Comment: Say $-1$, so you have $-y$.

Comment: Ah...any non-zero element of the definition field. Yes, indeed. I added that possibility, thank you.

Comment: thx for this guys, the claim has to be true, cause the task was to end up with that relationship

Comment: I've just seen another very similar example, but where they actually give the relation (where the difference to the previous is the k): 
$S^{-1}DS=kC$
Does this last relation make the claim true?
I can't really see how your derivation becomes $\mathbf{x} = S^{-1} \mathbf{y}$, could you please explain where you see it, maybe something obvious Im missing.